# getting input dropdown text value based on data attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having the following drop down input tag and I want to get the default vased on the data-id attribute. I have tried the solution below but does not work.

HTML

```
 <select id="expiryMonth" data-id="ExpiryMonth">
                        <option value="01" selected="selected">January</option>
                        <option value="02">February </option>
                        <option value="03">March</option>
                        <option value="04">April</option>
                        <option value="05">May</option>
                        <option value="06">June</option>
                        <option value="07">July</option>
                        <option value="08">August</option>
                        <option value="09">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  var expiryYear = $('input[data-id="ExpiryMonth"]');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**by data-id:**

-text

```
$('select[data-id="ExpiryMonth"] option:selected').text();
```

-value

```
$('select[data-id="ExpiryMonth"] option:selected').val();
```

**by id**

-text

```
$("#expiryMonth option:selected").text();
```

-value

```
$("#expiryMonth option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
   var expiryMonthText = $('select[data-id="ExpiryMonth"]').find("option:selected").val();


   var expiryMonthVal = $('select[data-id="ExpiryMonth"]').find("option:selected").text();
```